# The number $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n}-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n\right]$ is always an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

For each $n$ consider the expression $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n}-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n\right]$$

I am trying to prove by induction that this is an integer for all $n$.

In the base case $n=1$, it ends up being $1$.

I am trying to prove the induction step:

- if $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n}-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n\right]$ is an integer, then so is
  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n+1}-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{n+1}\right]$.

I have tried expanding it, but didn't get anywhere.

Comment: What you need for the induction is $F_n = F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$.  So once you know $F_0$ and $F_1$ are integers, you can use induction to get all $F_n$ are integers.

Comment: You might have a look at some similar posts, like http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906584/the-number-3-sqrt5n3-sqrt5n-is-an-integer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try writing
$$
\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n = \frac{a_n+b_n\sqrt{5}}{2}
$$
with $a_1=b_1=1$ and
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}+b_{n+1}\sqrt{5}}{2} = \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{a_n+b_n\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)
$$
see what you get, then repeat as much as you need to with $\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n$.

Comment: It took me awhile to figure out what you wanted me to do, but I think I got it now. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $\rm\ \ \ \phi^{\:n+1}\!-\:\bar\phi^{\:n+1} =\ (\color{#0a0}{\phi+\bar\phi})\ (\phi^n-\:\bar\phi^n)\ \color{#c00}{-\ \phi\:\bar\phi}\,\ (\phi^{\:n-1}\!-\:\bar\phi^{\:n-1})\ $ by [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/678917/242).

Substituting $\rm\ \color{#0a0}{\phi+\bar\phi}\, =\ 1\, =\, \color{#c00}{-\phi\bar\phi}\ $ then dividing by $\:\phi-\bar\phi = \sqrt 5\:$ the above becomes $\rm\:f_{n+1} = f_n + f_{n-1}\,$ so $\rm\,f_0,\:\!f_1\in\Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\, $ all $\rm\,f_n\in\Bbb Z\,$ by induction, using the recurrence.