# If $x+\frac1x=5$ find $x^5+\frac1{x^5}\,$ [recurrence for power sums]

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, polynomials, recurrence-relations, symmetric-polynomials

If $x>0$ and $\,x+\dfrac{1}{x}=5,\,$ find $\,x^5+\dfrac{1}{x^5}$.

Is there any other way find it?
$$
\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\left(x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)=23\cdot 110.
$$

Thanks

Comment: Why not just solve the quadratic and substitute for $x$ as in Nitish's answer.

Comment: Your equation there looks fine - expand LHS to get $x^5+x^{-5}+x+x^{-1}$ and you know $x+x^{-1}$. The other ways in the answers do it differently.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Key Idea** $ $ The recurrence $f_{n+2} =(a\!+\!b)\,f_{n+1}\!- ab\, f_n\,$ for the power sums $\,a^n+b^n\,$ arises simply by multiplying the first-order recurrences for $\,a^n,\, b^n$ (in operator form). If linear differential or difference operators $L,M\,$ kill $\,f,g,\,$ i.e. $\color{#c00}{Lf} = 0 = \color{#0a0}{Mg}\,\,$ and $\,L,M\,$ have *constant* coefficients then they **commute** $\,LM = ML,\,$ so their product (composition) $\,LM\,$ kills $f+g,\,$ viz.

$\qquad\ \begin{align} LM(f\!+\!g) \,&=\, LMf + LMg\ \ \ [\text{the composition $LM$ is linear, by $\,L,M\,$ linear}]\\[.2em]
&=\, M\color{#c00}{Lf} + L\color{#0a0}{M g}\ \ \ [\text{by $L,M$ commute}]\\[.2em]
&=\,\ \ \ \ \ \ \:\!    \color{#c00}0\, +\, \color{#0a0}0
\end{align}$

e.g. with $\, D = \frac{d}{dx}$ the derivative w.r.t. $\,x\,$ and $\,L= D\!-\!i,\ M = D\!+\!i$

$$ (D\!-\!i)e^{ix}\! = 0 = (D\!+\!i)e^{-ix}\Rightarrow\, (D\!-\!i)(D\!+\!i)\,\frac{e^{ix}\!+e^{-ix}}2=0,\ \ {\rm i.e.}\ \ (D^2\!+1)\cos(x) = 0\ \ $$

Similarly, as below, we can *discover* a second-order recurrence for the power sums $f_n = a^n + \color{#c0f}b^n\,$ by multiplying the first order recurrences for $\,a^n\,$ and $\,b^n.\,$ Specializing $\,\color{#c0f}{b = a^{-1}}\,$ yields a recurrence enabling us to quickly compute OP's sought values from initial values $ f_0 = 1,\ f_1 = 5.$

To do so it is convenient to express recurrences in polynomial operator form using the linear shift operator $ S $ such that $\ S g_n = g_{n+1}.\,$ Notice that $\,g_n = a^n\,$ satisfies $\,  S a^n = a^{n+1} = a a^n\,$  therefore $\, \color{#c00}0 = Sa^n - a a^n = \color{#c00}{(S-a)a^n}.\,$ Similarly $\,\color{#0a0}{(S-b)b^n = 0}.\,$  $\,S\!-\!a\,$ and $\,S\!-\!b\,$ *commute* because their coefficients $\,a,b\,$ are *constants*  w.r.t. $\,n\,$ i.e. $\,Sag = a Sg,\,$ and $\, Sbg = bSg,\,$ hence

$\qquad (S\!-\!a)(S\!-\!b)(a^n\!+b^n)\, =\, (S\!-\!b)\color{#c00}{(S\!-\!a)a^n} + (S\!-\!a)\color{#0a0}{(S\!-\!b)b^n}\, =\, \color{#c00}0 + \color{#0a0}0\, =\, 0$

Thus $\ \ 0 = (S\!-\!a)(S\!-\!b) f_n = (S^2\!-(a\!+\!b)S+ab)f_n = \underbrace{f_{n+2}\!-(a\!+\!b)\,f_{n+1}\!+ab\, f_n}_{\large{\rm recurrence\ \ for}\ \ f_n}.$

Many further examples are in the "Linked" questions list in the sidebar $\Longrightarrow$

Comment: @BillDubuque: Isn't the initial value $f_0=2$? Great answer by the way!

Comment: @BillDubuque Sorry to bother, but I stumbled upon a similar question which caused problems for me before with x^7 instead. What does it mean in math when operators "kill" functions. I'm so amazed on where the intuition to approach it this way came from. Otherwise, very cool answer :)

Comment: @Hushus46 $L$ kills $f$ means $\,Lf = 0\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque oh, simple, thanks!

Comment: @BillDubuque also, where did the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ come from after the implication in the example you have given using $D$?

Comment: @Hushus46 The argument shows that $D^2+1$ will kill any linear combination $c_1\, e^{ix}+c_2\, e^{-x}$ with constant coefficients $c_i.$ I chose the coefficients $c_i = 1/2$ in order to obtain $\cos(x).\,$  The point was to give a familiar warm-up example to help motivate the analogous less well-known discrete case that follows.

Comment: @BillDubuque Ah okay, thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 23):

Observe the recurrence relation $$x^{n+1} + x^{-(n+1)} = (x+x^{-1})(x^n+x^{-n}) - (x^{n-1} + x^{-(n-1)}).$$

This immediately gives us the specific recurrence $$f_{n+1} = 5f_n - f_{n-1}, \quad f_0 = 2, \quad f_1 = 5,$$ where $f_n = x^n + x^{-n}$.

Comment: See my answer for a simple general way to *discover* this recurrence.

Answer (score 18):

\begin{align}
x+\frac{1}{x}&=5\\
x^2+1&=5x\\
x^2-5x+1&=0\\
x &=\frac{1}{2} \left( 5 +\sqrt{21}\right)\\
x^5+\frac{1}{x^5}&=\cdots
\end{align}

Comment: The key idea for such problems is to avoid unnecessary operations...

Answer (score 13):

Using the factorization identity $$a^5+b^5=(a+b)(a^4-a^3b+a^2b^2-ab^3+b^4),$$ we obtain
\begin{align}
x^5+\frac{1}{x^5}&=\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(x^4-x^2+1-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}\right) \\ &=\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^4-5x^2-5-5\frac{1}{x^2}\right) \\&=\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^4
-5\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2+5\right)=5(5^4-5\cdot5^2+5)=2525,
\end{align}
since
$$
\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^4=x^4+4x^2+6+\frac{4}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}.
$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Expand (binomial formula) $\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^3$ and then $\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^5$. (No need for even powers.)

Comment: We can also achieve this insight by "reducing" the recurrence in @heropup's Answer to skip every other term, $f_{n+2} = 23f_n - f_{n-2}$, so $f_5 = 23f_3 - f_1$.

Comment: @hardmath +1. Absolutely. The recursion from binomial formula just jumps out due to $x^{n-k}x^{-k} = x^{n-2k}$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:
$$\left( x + \frac{1}{x}\right)^5 = x^5 + \frac{1}{x^5} + 5\left(x^3  + \frac{1}{x^3}\right)
+ 10\left(x + \frac{1}{x} \right)$$
$$x^3  + \frac{1}{x^3} = \left(x + \frac{1}{x} \right)\left(x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} - 1 \right)$$

$$\left( x + \frac{1}{x}\right)^2 - 2 = x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Since the other answers have worked directly with powers of $x$, an alternative perspective may be interesting. Let $\tau =\ln x$. Then $x^n+x^{-n}=e^{n\tau}+e^{-n\tau}=2\cosh n\tau$. For $n=1$ in particular we have $2\cosh\tau=x+x^{-1}=5$ by assumption, and so we may write  $$x^n+x^{-n}=2\cosh(n\tau)=2\cosh(n\cosh^{-1}(5/2)).$$ So this problem can be interpreted as in terms of particular inversion of the hyperbolic cosine. This in fact serves as one definition of the *Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind* as $T_n(x)=\cosh(n\cosh^{-1}x))$. So what we're after is $2T_5(5/2)$.

One can develop recursive methods of computing $T_n(x)$, but I'll settle with quoting the Wikipedia page to get $$T_5(x)=16x^5-20x^3+5x\implies 2T_5(5/2)=5^5-5^4+5^2=\boxed{2525}.$$

Answer (score 1):

First find out $x^2 + x^{-2}$ and then $x^3 + x^{-3}$ by expanding and then at last find the required answer by taking power $5$.

Answer (score 1):

OP seems to have found a fairly efficient means of calculating (or there is one implicit in the question) as follows:

Let $a_n=x^n+x^{-n}$

Then we have $a_n a_{n-1}=a_{2n-1}+a_1$ or $$a_{2n-1}=a_na_{n-1}-a_1$$

And $a_n^2=a_{2n}+2$ or $$a_{2n}=a_n^2-2$$

So we have, with $a_1=5$ $$a_2=a_1^2-2=23$$

And $$a_3=a_2a_1-a_1=110$$

So that $$a_5=a_3a_2-a_1=2525$$

I put this up as an answer, because the method looks to work pretty efficiently for higher powers.

Answer (score 0):

There is the famous explicit  formula

$$
\frac{x^n+\dfrac{1}{x^n}}{\left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{n}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}} (-1)^k \frac{n}{n-k} \binom{n-k}{k}\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{-2k}.
$$