# Proof of closed form of recursively defined sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be defined by $f(1) = 5, f(2) = 13$, and for $n \ge 2, f(n) = 2f(n - 2) + f(n - 1)$. Prove that $f(n) = 3\cdot 2^n + (-1)^n$ for all $n \in N$

So far I've proved that $f(n)$ is true when $n = 1, 2$.
For $k \ge 3$, assume that $p(j)$ is true for all $j \in N, j < k$

Now I want to prove that $p(k)$ is true for all $k \in N$

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Induction on $n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us do an induction on $n$.

- **Induction start.** $f(1)=5=3\cdot 2-1$ and $f(2)=13=3\cdot 4+1$ (note that we really need the first *two* values in the induction start, because the recurrence uses the preceeding two values).
- **Induction hypothesis.** For some $n\ge 1$, we assume that we proved the formula for all $k\le n$.
- **Induction step.** We show that the formula then also holds for $n+1\ge 2$:

$$f(n+1)=2f(n-1)+f(n)=2\cdot (3\cdot 2^{n-1}+(-1)^{n-1})+3\cdot 2^n + (-1)^n=3\cdot 2^{n+1}+(-1)^{n+1}$$

Comment: That helped a lot! Thanks!

Comment: See my answer for a general view on why this works

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try induction. Assume that the statement holds for $n$ and from that, prove it holds for $n+1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ Let $\,S g(n) = g(n\!+\!1)$ be the shift operator. $(S-2)(2^n) = 0 = (S+1)(-1^n)$ so their product $(S-2)(S+1) = S^2\!-S-2$ kills $\, f_n = c\,2^n + d (-1)^n\,$ for any $\,c,d\,$ independent of $\,n.$ Therefore we deduce $\, 0 = (S^2\!-S-2)f_n = f_{n+2} - f_{n} - 2f_n,\ $ i.e $\ f_{n+2} = f_{n+1} + 2 f_n.$

**Remark** $\ $ See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/678917/242) for another example and further explanation. This explains how the proof works in TooOldForMath's answer.

Comment: I wish I had an upvote left for today. You always know how to surprise with a general perspective.