# Finding $x-\frac{1}{x}$ if $x^{3}-\frac{1}{x^{3}}=76$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x$ is a real number that satisfies $x^{3}-\frac{1}{x^{3}}=76$, determine the value of $x-\frac{1}{x}$.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678650/if-x-frac1x-5-find-x5-frac1x5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u=x-\frac {1}{x} $

$$ u^3 = 76-3u$$

$$(u-4)(u^2+4u+19)=0$$

$$u=4$$

$$x-   \frac {1}{x}  =4$$

Answer (score 8):

*Hint:* Expand $\left(x-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^3$.

Comment: I did, and the result was $x^{3}-3\left(x-x^{-1}\right)-x^{3}$. But then I got stuck, what am I supposed to do next?

Comment: @user569622 There is a mistake in what you wrote above. You have $$\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^3 = x^3-\frac{1}{x^3} - 3\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ Writing $X = x-\frac{1}{x}$, this means $$X^3 = 76 - 3X$$

Comment: @ClementC. Thank you, I didn't realize I can write the equation like that. :)

Answer (score 0):

$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ and note that $(x-\frac{1}{x})^2 =x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}-2$ then if we set $(x-\frac{1}{x})=t$ we have $t(t^2+3)=76$ now find $t$.