# The number $(3+\sqrt{5})^n+(3-\sqrt{5})^n$ is an integer

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, induction

Prove by induction that this number is an integer:

$$u_n=(3+\sqrt{5})^n+(3-\sqrt{5})^n$$

#### Progress

I assumed that it holds for $n$ and I tried to do it for $n+1$ but the algebra gets quite messy and I'm unable to prove that the following term is an integer: $\sqrt{5}((3+\sqrt{5})^n-(3-\sqrt{5})^n)$

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I assumed that it holds for $n$ and I tried to do it for $n+1$ but the algebra get quite messy and I'm unable to prove that the following term is an integer :$\sqrt{5}((3+\sqrt{5})^n-(3-\sqrt{5})^n)$

Comment: @user143201 It's much less messy (almost trivial!) if you exploit the innate algebraic **symmetry** - here the *multiplicativity* of the *conjugation* map $\,\alpha = j + k\sqrt{5}\,\to\, \bar\alpha = j-k\sqrt{5}.\ $ See my answer for details.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1903099

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Outline:** For the (strong) induction step, we can use the fact that
$$(3+\sqrt{5})^{n+1}+(3-\sqrt{5})^{n+1}=\left[(3+\sqrt{5})^{n}+(3-\sqrt{5})^{n}\right]\left[(3+\sqrt{5})+(3-\sqrt{5})\right]-(3+\sqrt{5})(3-\sqrt{5})\left[(3+\sqrt{5})^{n-1}+(3-\sqrt{5})^{n-1}\right].$$

Note that $(3+\sqrt{5})+(3-\sqrt{5})$ and $(3+\sqrt{5})(3-\sqrt{5})$ are integers.

**Remark:** There are better "non-induction" ways. For example, imagine expanding each of $(3+\sqrt{5})^n$ and $(3-\sqrt{5})^n$, using the Binomial Theorem. Now add.  The terms in odd powers of $\sqrt{5}$ cancel.

Comment: In general, if you have a monic polynomial $x^2+ax+b$ with integer coefficients and (possibly complex) roots $\alpha,\beta$, $\alpha^n+\beta^n$ is an integer for any $n$, from $\alpha+\beta=-a$, $\alpha\beta=b$ integers and $\alpha^{n+1}+\beta^{n+1}=(\alpha^n+\beta^n)(\alpha+\beta)-\alpha\beta(\alpha^{n-1}+\beta^{n-1})$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff:  Your comment is clearer than my answer, an example of how greater generality can be simpler.

Comment: Does induction holds for $n-1$ ?

Comment: You can frame the argument as strong induction. (If the result holds for all $k\le n$, it holds at $n+1$). For details, please see Wikipedia or your book. Or we can frame it as ordinary induction, letting $P(n)$ be the assertion that the expression is an integer at $n-1$ and $n$. Verify that $P(1)$ holds (two things to check). Then use the formula displayed in the answer to show that if $P(n)$ holds then $P(n+1)$ holds.

Comment: @Pedro Another simple way to view it is via the multiplicativity of conjugation - see my answer.

Answer (score 11):

From the theory of sequences defined by a [linear recurrence relation with constant coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients/%20linear%20recurrence%20relation%20with%20constant%20coefficients), the sequence $u_n$ satisfies $u_{n+2}=6u_{n+1}-4u_n$ and $u_0=2$ and $u_1=6$.

Then, if you assume that $u_n$ and $u_{n+1}$ are integers, it follows immediately that $u_{n+2}$ is also an integer. You can write a strong induction from this to have a complete proof.

Answer (score 6):

Let $v_n = (3+\sqrt{5})^n - (3-\sqrt{5})^n$, then
$$
u_1 = 6, v_1 = 2\sqrt{5}
$$
And
$$
u_{n+1} = (3+\sqrt{5})(3+\sqrt{5})^n + (3-\sqrt{5})(3-\sqrt{5})^n = 6u_n + \sqrt{5}v_n
$$
$$
v_{n+1} = (3+\sqrt{5})(3+\sqrt{5})^n - (3-\sqrt{5})(3-\sqrt{5})^n = 6v_n +\sqrt{5}u_n
$$
If $v_n$ is an integer multiple of $\sqrt{5}$ and $u_n$ is an integer, then $v_{n+1}$ is an integer multiple of $\sqrt{5}$ and $u_{n+1}$ is an integer.

Answer (score 5):

If $n$ is odd then for all reals 
$x, y$
we have
$$(x+y)^{n} + (x-y)^{n} = 2x^n + 2\sum_{j\ \text{odd}}\binom{n}{j}x^{j}y^{n-j};$$
if $n$ is even then for all reals $x, y$ we have
$$(x+y)^{n} + (x-y)^{n} = 2x^n + 2y^n + 2\sum_{j\ \text{even}}\binom{n}{j}x^{j}y^{n-j}.$$
Putting
$x := 3$ and $y := \sqrt{5}$
finishes the proof,
for the irrational terms are all cancelled out.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $\, $ By induction $\,\overbrace{\alpha^n,\:\overline\alpha^{\,n}}^{\alpha\ =\ 3\,+\sqrt 5}\! = \overbrace{j \pm k\sqrt{5}}^{\large j,\,k\ \in\ \Bbb Z}\,$ are $\,\color{#c00}{\overbrace{\rm conjugate}^{\textstyle {\overline{\alpha^n}}=\,\color{#c00}{{\overline\alpha}^n}}},\,$  so their sum $= 2j\in\Bbb Z.\,$ $\ \bf\small QED$

(with easy inductive step:  $\,\ \overline{\alpha^{n+1}} =\, \color{#0a0}{\overline{\alpha\,\alpha^n} 
=\,\overline\alpha}\,\color{#c00}{\overline{\alpha^n}}\,\overset{\color{#c00}{\rm induct}}=\overline\alpha\,\color{#c00}{{\overline\alpha}^n} = {\overline\alpha}^{\,n+1}\ $ by $\ \color{#0a0}{\overline{xy}\, =\, \overline x\, \overline y}\:\!)$

**Remark** $ $ Hence we see that the proof is a special case of the $n$-ary inductive extension of the $\color{#0a0}{\text{multiplicativity}}$ of conjugation: $\, \overline{\alpha_1\cdots\, \alpha_n}\, =\, \overline\alpha_1\cdots\,\overline\alpha_n,\,$ in our special *power* case: $\,\alpha_i = \alpha.\,$  The same proof works for any quadratic integer $\,\alpha.\,$ As always: $ $[exploit innate symmetry!](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20exploit%20%22innate%20symmetry%22)

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/48533/242) for an extension to computing the *parity* of such power sums using the natural extension of parity to some quadratic number rings.

Comment: i.e. the sum is an integer since it is the [trace](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/906584/242) $\,w+\bar w\,$ of a quadratic integer $\,w.\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Roots_of_the_characteristic_polynomial) -- the solutions of $a_n=Aa_{n-1}+Ba_{n-2}$ are given by $a_n=C\lambda_1^n+D\lambda_2^n$ if $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2$, where $C,D$ are constants created by $a_0,a_1$, and $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are the solutions of $\lambda^2-A\lambda-B=0$ (the characteristic polynomial), and $a_n=C\lambda^n+Dn\lambda^n$ if $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda$.

$u_n=(3+\sqrt{5})^n+(3-\sqrt{5})^n$.

In this case, you want $\lambda_1=3+\sqrt{5}$, $\lambda_2=3-\sqrt{5}$, $C,D$ created by $u_0=2$, $u_1=6$.

Apply [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

$\lambda_1+\lambda_2=6=A$, $\lambda_1\lambda_2=4=-B$.

The characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^2-6\lambda+4=0$.

The recurrence relation is $u_{n+1}=6u_n-4u_{n-1}$ with $u_0=2$, $u_1=6$.

$u_n$ is an integer because $u_0$, $u_1$ are integers and the recurrence relation shows that $u_2=6u_1-4u_0\in\mathbb Z$, etc. You could use induction here.

(I.e., if $u_k$, $u_{k+1}$ are integers for some $k\in\mathbb Z$, $k\ge 0$, then $u_{k+2}=6u_{k+1}-4u_k$ is also an integer).

Furthermore, $u_n$ is the next integer greater than $(3+\sqrt{5})^n$ because

$3-\sqrt{5}=$

$=\sqrt{3^2}-\sqrt{2^2+1}\in(0,1)$

because more generally for $m\in\mathbb Z$, $m\ge 1$,

$\sqrt{(m+1)^2}=1+\sqrt{m^2}$

$<1+\sqrt{m^2+1}$.

Similar facts are applicable for [Pell's equations](https://www.google.lt/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=8y92Wd7_BLCr8wfEtLqwAg&gws_rd=ssl#q=pell+equation). See, e.g., [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2309700/236182).

In this case, you want $x_1=3$, $y_1=1$, $D=5$,

but $3^2-5\cdot 1^2\neq 1$, so a Pell equation isn't easily possible for this sequence, unlike in [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1903099/why-is-2-sqrt3n2-sqrt3n-an-integer/2370432#2370432).