# Arithmetic of integers (based on mathematical induction)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $$f(n) = (3+\sqrt{5})^n + (3-\sqrt{5})^n$$ show that $f(n)$ is an integer and that $$f(n+1)= 6f(n) - 4f(n-1).$$ Deduce that the next integer greater than $(3+\sqrt{5})^n$ is divisible by $2^n.$
I am not getting a way to approach such a question. So, please help me regarding that...

Comment: Have you tried it for small $n$?  This screams for an induction proof.  The point is that the $\sqrt 5$'s cancel out.   I recommend Aurturo Magidin's answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/dominoes-and-induction-or-how-does-induction-work/19488#19488) for a good intro

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.  You'll get a lot more help if your questions are easy to read.

Comment: It is a lot easier to see that $f(n)$ is an integer once you have established the given formula for $f(n+1)$ :)z

Answer (score 0):

*Proof for showing* $f(n) = (3+\sqrt{5})^n + (3-\sqrt{5})^n$ *is an integer* :

By binomial expansion we see that :

$$(3+\sqrt{5})^n = C_0 + C_1 \cdot 3^{n - 1} \cdot 5 ^{1/2} + C_2 \cdot 3^{n - 2} \cdot 5^{2/2} + \dots + C_n \cdot 5^{n/2}$$

$$(3-\sqrt{5})^n = C_0 - C_1 \cdot 3^{n - 1} \cdot 5 ^{1/2} +  C_2 \cdot 3^{n - 2} \cdot 5^{2/2} + \dots + (-1)^r \cdot 3^{n - r} \cdot 5^{r/2} + \dots + (-1)^n \cdot 5^{n/2}$$

Adding these two equations we notice that for $n$ that is odd the respective terms cancel out in the above equations. So only the terms for which $n$ is even are present in $(3+\sqrt{5})^n + (3-\sqrt{5})^n$ and thus $f(n)$ is an integer.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346716/mathematical-induction-problem-let-s-n-left-3-sqrt5-rightn-left3?rq=1) is an induction based proof.