# Prove that the next integer greater than $(3+\sqrt{5})^n$ is divisible by $2^n$ where $n$ is a natural number.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

Prove that the next integer greater than $(3+\sqrt{5})^n$ is divisible by $2^n$ where $n$ is a natural number. The problem is given in a chapter of induction.
It is actually a part of this whole question:

If $S_n = (3+\sqrt{5})^n + (3-\sqrt{5})^n$, show that $S_n$ is an integer and that  $S_{n+1} = 6S_n - 4S_{n-1}$.
Deduce that the next integer greater than $(3+\sqrt{5})^n$ is divisible by $2^n$.

I could do the first two parts. The first part I have done by induction and the second part by simply using the given formula. I cannot proceed at all in the third part. I think it may need induction. Please give any solutions regarding the third one and see whether the second one can be proved using induction.

Comment: How about showing that $(3+\sqrt{5})^n+(3-\sqrt{5})^n$ is divisible by $2^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ using induction? Part I and II are shown [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906584/the-number-3-sqrt5n3-sqrt5n-is-an-integer?rq=1).

Comment: How do I prove that and how can I be sure that $(3+\sqrt{5})^n+(3-\sqrt{5})^n$ is the next integer greater than $(3+\sqrt{5})^n$.

Comment: For the third part:  You know that $S_n$ is an integer greater than $\left( 3+\sqrt 5\right)^n$.  If $\lceil \left( 3+\sqrt 5 \right)^n \rceil<S_n$  Then show that this implies $\left( 3-\sqrt 5\right)^n>1$ (a contradiction).

Answer (score 2):

If we denote $a:=3+\sqrt{5}$ and $b:=3-\sqrt{5}$, then $a$ and $b$ are the roots of the polynomial $$x^2-6x+4$$

Therefore , the number $s_n:=a^n+b^n$ satisfies the recursion :

$$s_1=6$$

$$s_2=28$$

$$s_n=6s_{n-1}-4s_{n-2}$$

Because of $0<b^n<1$ for $n\ge 1$, we have $\lceil a^n \rceil=s_n$

Suppose $s_n$ is divisble by $2^n$ and $s_{n-1}$ is divisible by $2^{n-1}$ (This claim is true for $n=2$) . Then, $s_{n+1}=6s_n-4s_{n-1}$ is divisble by $2^{n+1}$ because $6s_n$ and $4s_{n-1}$ are both divisble by $2^{n+1}$. Therefore, the induction step is completed.

Comment: Both are only divisible by $2^n$.

Comment: @WimC Fixed. I got the indeces wrong!

Comment: I did not understand the recursion part.

Comment: @user321525 Usually, the calculation is done in the other direction. We know the recursion and calculate the characteristic equation and derive the general formula. To get the characteristic equation, we insert the Ansatz $s_n=x^n$ into the recursion $s_n=us_{n-1}+vs_{n-2}$ and get $x^n-ux^{n-1}-vx^{n-2}=0$ divided by $x^{n-2}$ this gives $x^2-ux-v=0$, the characteristic equation . If the roots $a$ and $b$ are distinct, we can show that there are constants $c_1$ and $c_2$, such that $s_n=c_1a^n+c_2b^n$. The constants can be calculated by using $s_1$ and $s_2$

Comment: You can try to show the recursion by induction , a good additional exercise.

Comment: Now how do I do that?

Comment: The induction proof ? Show $s_n=a^n+b^n$ first for $n=1$ and $n=2$. Then,  assume $s_{n-1}=a^{n-1}+b^{n-1}$ and $s_{n-2}=a^{n-2}+b^{n-2}$. Plugging into the recursion should give $s_n=a^n+b^n$