# Prove $(2+\sqrt{13})^n + (2-\sqrt{13})^n$ is natural number without using binomial theorem

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, induction, recurrence-relations

Question is as stated in the title.

I attempted to prove this by induction on $n$. Base case is just $2$, so it obviously holds. Assuming it holds for $n=k$, then the case for $n=k+1$ can be converted into something like $2((2+\sqrt{13})^k + (2-\sqrt{13})^k) + \sqrt{13}(2+\sqrt{13})^k - \sqrt{13}(2-\sqrt{13})^k$. The first part is a natural number by our inductive hypothesis, but I'm not sure what to do with the second part: $\sqrt{13}(2+\sqrt{13})^k - \sqrt{13}(2-\sqrt{13})^k$. I can factor out another natural number from this part, and convert it into: $\sqrt{13}((2+\sqrt{13})^k + (2-\sqrt{13})^k) - 2\sqrt{13}(2-\sqrt{13})^k$, but I'm not sure how I can proceed from there.

I'm not sure what tags to put, but I encountered this problem in a combinatorics course, so I added a tag for that. Also since it's about natural numbers, I think maybe there can be some insights from number theory, although it's not a typical number theory problem.

Comment: You can prove the recurrence relation: just check that $a_{k+2}=4a_{k+1}+9a_{k}$.

Comment: Anyway, what's wrong with using the binomial formula?

Comment: if we name $a_n =  (2+\sqrt{13})^n + (2-\sqrt{13})^n$  there is a linear constant coefficient recursion; what is $a_{n+2}$  as a simple expression in $a_{n+1}, a_n \; ?  \; \;$

Comment: Alternatively, prove with induction, at the same time that $(2+\sqrt{13})^k-(2-\sqrt{13})^k$ is an integer multiplied by $\sqrt{13}$

Comment: Because the recurrence is second-order, you will want to have two consecutive base cases.  $n=0$ and $n=1$ work very nicely for this.

Comment: @richrow The problem just bans the use of binomial. It's not that I don't want to use it.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906584/the-number-3-sqrt5n3-sqrt5n-is-an-integer)

Comment: Follows immediately by induction using the well-know recurrence for power sums - see the linked dupes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let us write for each natural number $k$:

$$c_k = (2+\sqrt{13})^k,$$ and
$$d_k = (2-\sqrt{13})^k, $$ and
$$e_k = c_k +d_k.$$

Then $c_{n+2}$ satisfies
$$c_{n+2} = (4+4\sqrt{13}+4+9)c_n$$ $$=((8+4\sqrt{13}) + 9)c_n$$ $$= 4c_{n+1}+9c_n.$$
Likewise, $d_{n+2}$ satisfies
$$d_{n+2} = (4-4\sqrt{13}+4+9)d_n$$
$$=4d_{n+1}+9d_n.$$

Thus $e_{n+2} =c_{n+2}+d_{n+2}$ satisfies
$$e_{n+2} = 4e_{n+1}+9e_n.$$

So if $e_n$ is integral and $e_{n+1}$ is integral, then so is $e_{n+2}$. But what were $e_1$ and $e_2$ again...

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 6):

One good thing to know (and to verify) is that conjugation, i.e., the function that takes an element $x = m + n\sqrt{13}$ to its conjugate $\overline{x} = m - n\sqrt{13}$, preserves multiplication: $\overline{xy} = \overline{x} \cdot \overline{y}$.

Once you have this, then you can prove by induction that the conjugate of $(2 + \sqrt{13})^n$ is $(2 - \sqrt{13})^n$.

Finally, what can you say about an element plus its conjugate?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I accepted the other one because it feels more straight forward to me, but the idea you proposed also seem very interesting. So basically the idea is that taking conjugate of $(2+\sqrt{13})(2+\sqrt{13})^k$ gives $(2-\sqrt{13})(2-\sqrt{13})^k$ by inductive hypothesis and the preservation of multiplication, and adding an element to its conjugate always give an integer?

Comment: It sounds like you've roughly got the idea. Tastes differ, but to my taste this carries more conceptual snap. Anyway, pun a pin through it for now. The idea might pack an even greater punch one day after you've studied some modern algebra, particularly after you begin studying Galois theory.

Comment: Yes multiplication indeed preserves conjugation. It is a very clever answer! +1

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).